# Magento 2.3.4 - Need to Merge CSS on Page wise

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.4, merge-css

Many of them using Custom Theme with multiple custom modules. In custom module, we are calling particular css module on Layout xml file.

When we enable **Merge CSS file** option under `admin -> Stores > Settings > Configuration > In the panel on the left under Advanced > choose Developer`.

Currently, It merges all CSS into a single file which is loaded in the entire website. But, unwanted css (which are not related to the page) are also loaded.

I am looking to merge the CSS on page wise and working on it. If anyone have an idea about this please comment it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have analysed and noticed that by default Magento 2 version merging the CSS by Layout wise and with default (Theme Layout) xml file.

In order to load page wise CSS, we need to separate the custom CSS (for particular Page css) and mentioned it in the respective Layout file.

**For example:** In Product Page (Catalog product view)

```
app / code / [companyname] / [modulename] / view / frontend / layout / catalog_product_view.xml
```

Create the custom CSS files:

```
app / code / [companyname] / [modulename] / view / frontend / web / css / productpage.css (custom CSS file)
```

Add Custom CSS in the Layout File under head tag

```
<head>
<css src="[companyname]_[modulename]::css/productpage.css" />
</head>
```

After merging, default theme css and productpage.css will merge and load it.

Comment: The downside of this is that you the advantages of using `LESS` files (variables, mixins, ...)